# Extjs data binding in a form

Tags: apache-flex, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have just recently made a move from Adobe Flex to Sencha ExtJs.

I can't seem to find an equivalent of data binding in ExtJs where a form value depends on another form value.

e.g. I am creating an SMS window where i show the count of characters entered in a message field.

This is how i am doing in ExtJS. Also, the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/xxB4J/

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',{
       items: [
       {
            xtype: 'textarea',
            fieldLabel: 'Message',
            listeners: {
                change: function() {
                    var countLabel = this.up('window').down('#lbCharacterCount');
                    countLabel.setText(this.getValue().length + '/160 Characters');
                }
            }
        },
        {
            xtype: 'label',
            itemId: 'lbCharacterCount',
            text: '0/160 Characters'
        }
    ]

}).show();
```

Now, in Flex this was as simple as doing

```
<mx:Text text="{message.text.length.toString()}/160 Characters}" />
```

So, just want to know if there is some sort of similar data binding in ExtJS? or the way i am doing is the only way of doing it?

Thank you

Comment: Angular JS has some data-binding like features; I don't know about extJS, though.  Maybe you could use the two together?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you could use a textarea configuration:

Sencha: 
[maxLength](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.TextArea-cfg-maxLength) and [maxLengthText](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.TextArea-cfg-maxLengthText)

or is the control field editable ?

Comment: Thanks. Yup, textarea is editable. Count label updates as you type.